# How do I split contents in a text that would include two or more different themes (context) in NLP?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, text-classification, nltk

For example, a text: "The airlines have affected by Corona since march 2020 a crime has been detected in Noia village this morning"

the output should be:

- The airline companies have affected by Corona since march 2020
- a crime has been detected in Noia village this morning

the text has no Breaks. I know it is not a one-click solution, but if anyone knows a methodology or techniques to solve such a problem, please provide me with resources.

Answer (score 1):

First reading the question I thought this is very easy and I started searching and trying out some libraries (i.e. nltk, and spacy). [Here are my attempts](https://github.com/fatemerhmi/sample_codes/blob/master/NLP/split_sentence.ipynb) and clearly showing that none of them works. I was thinking that these libraries will generate a parsing tree or a context-free grammar to detect sentences, but they are splitting based on a certain characters such as periods or commas.

So the other solution is to learn a classifier that learns the boundaries of sentences. A simple solution can be to use random forest classifier or SVM to serve as a binary classification task for each token. But the missing part is the data to train the model on and what to consider as labels (a BIO tagging scheme is a good idea here). I include two papers here that can be a good starting point for you to first read their methodology and use the datasets they are mentioning to do the task.

- Du, Jinhua, Yan Huang, and Karo Moilanen. ["AIG Investments. AI at the FinSBD task: Sentence boundary detection through sequence labelling and BERT fine-tuning."](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W19-5513.pdf) Proceedings of the First Workshop on Financial Technology and Natural Language Processing. 2019.
- Rudrapal, Dwijen, et al. ["Sentence boundary detection for social media text."](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2395996/13_rp.pdf?sequence=3) (2015).